# Macbook Air (mid 2012) Efi Firmware Downgrade –to original

Tags: macbook-pro, efi, firmware, downgrade

I want to bring back my beloved Macbook Air 2012 (MBA5,2) to its 'original firmware'. I have identified the file as MBA51_00EF_B01.scap, which I extracted using unpkg over the downloadable offered by Apple here: [MacBook Air EFI Firmware Update 2.5](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1592?locale=en_US).

That version allows one to install OSX 10.7.4, which is the (oldest) OS that shipped with this machine. That will allow me to reactive an old M-Audio sound interface that only works with Lion OSX. But also to experience and use this hardware performing the lightest, for I mainly use it as a working station with vintage software.

Presently I have Mountain Lion (10.8.4) installed, but once I had El Capitan which upgraded me to BootROM MBA51.00EF.B04 and SMC 2.5f9. I managed to downgrade the SMC firmware to version 2.5f7, which is compatible with 10.7.4–I used rEFIt and SmcFlasher.efi for it. But Bootrom remains MBA51.00EF.B04.

I followed [this guide](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103720/how-to-downgrade-efi-firmware-back-to-version-1-6) and ran the following command in the Terminal:
/usr/sbin/bless -mount / -firmware "MBA51_00EF_B01.scap" --recovery --verbose

Firmware preloads successfully. But when I reboot to start the installation a black screen remains during three continuous fast reboots (I guess trying to install the new firmware). Then it boots normally and no firmware downgrade happened.

Any idea why this is happening? Are there any other methods to load the BootROM, supposing that it is just being refused by "bless" for being older that the installed one?

Hope this contributes and appeals to those willing to revive the past.

----- UPDATE 30/07/19 -----

Still trying to downgrade firmware in MBA mid2012.

Normal method via 'bless' command and extracted .scap didn't work. I just get a longer black screen and no firmware update, like to someone [here](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/guide-how-to-get-back-old-efi-after-downgrade-from-yosemite.1803934/) and [here](http://www.cyberforum.ru/mac-os/thread1568357.html#post13742716) (with the same model).

I presume apple introduced the iOS policy of no-return in newer firmwares?

An alternative way would be to inject the older firmware [with 'flashrom' over linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oScvBTR_L4Q), but I don't have another MBA with original firmware from where to extract it. Someone uploaded a similar dump [here](https://www.ghostlyhaks.com/forum/efi-firmware-dumps-requests/609-a1465-dump-or-cleaned-bin-needed). But it is for MBA2012 11" i7, mine is MBA2012 13" i5. I guess the firmware is the same, but double risk to brick it.

Comment: Have you tried just using [macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) to install the original version of OS X that came with your Mac?. In other words, hold down the Shift-Option-⌘-R keys at startup. In your case, you may want to try the Command (⌘)-R keys, since the newest OS X installed was El Capitan.

Comment: Unfortunately my SSD doesn't have the Recovery partition anymore... That's the reason why I'm trying to install the original Lion 10.7.4 from a downloaded .dmg

Comment: ... Thanks for the contribution David!

Comment: I thought you downloaded the original operation system from the internet. You should not need a recovery partition. Read the section titled **If you never installed macOS Sierra 10.12.4** at the Apple website [How to reinstall macOS from macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904). Again, I repeat: *You should not need a Recovery partition on the internal drive.* You should be able to completely erase the internal drive and reinstall the original version of OS X downloaded from the internet.

Comment: Besides, you can not install Lion from an Apple purchase without first having Snow Leopard (OS X 10.6.6 to 10.6.8) installed. Read the system requirements at [OS X Lion (10.7)](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion). Unfortunately in your case, you probably can not install Snow Leopard on that model Mac. *It is too new.* You would have to find an older Mac that is both Snow Leopard and Lion compatible. Connect the drive either internally or by using a USB shell. Next, install Snow Leopard, then upgrade to Lion. Once you have done this, you can put the drive in your 2012 Mac.

Comment: Hi again David. I am trying indeed to install a Lion version that I downloaded many years from the internet, it used to work in another machine I don't have anymore.

Comment: When you installed Lion on the other machine, did you upgrade from Snow Leopard or did you do a clean install on an erased drive?

Comment: ... When I select the USB installation drive at booting I get a grey window, with a 'null' circle in the center. I have assumed so far that Lion cannot be installed in this machine because the firmware is too new, since Apple firmware pages indicate ML as requirement for all firmwares after B02. Therefore I try to downgrade from B04 to B01. Would say my interpretation is correct? Or am I getting the 'null' symbol because I'm not jumping from Snow Leopard? Thanks a lot for the illuminations!

Comment: Sorry didn't see your previous question. I installed Lion from scratch by then. Maybe I should try erasing my SSD first and see if the installer works then... :s

Comment: I can confirm that installing from an empty SSD doesn´t make any difference. Didn´t have the chance to upgrade to Lion from Snow Leopard, since my system is 'too new' for SL. But I'm afraid it is the newer firmware locking the installation, because I installed once Lion from scratched (in a hackintosh).